# HTML from SharePoint List data

Tags: 2013, list, javascript

How can I write a script that would get data from a SharePoint List column so I could use it in an HTML page

Is there a JS library out there that I could use, if so, what is it and where can I get it?

**For example:**

If I had a SharePoint site named "SiteName" and a SharePoint list that I named "ContactsTest" that had fields/columns named "First Name", "Last Name", "Location", ect. and I wanted to get the value of "First Name" and display it in my HTML page using JS. How would I implement this?

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: I believe that it is Microsoft SharePoint 2013.  The server is running a version of SharePoint Server 2016

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve this however you can check the below one. You need to get list items using JavaScript and then populate in HTML.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/retrieve-items-from-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-jav/) is another nice article that you can check. You may need to change the variables according to your list and site names etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No need to start from scratch with coding... that will be a long learning path

Microsoft developed CSR - Client Side Rendering, (since SP2013) Where you can use JavaScript to rewrite the SharePoint (HTML) output to anything your JavaScript skills let you do.

The [(Chrome) Browser Extension Cisar editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar) is a WYSYWIG editor that gives you all the JavaScript boilerplate code and takes care of adding the JS files (with JSLink) to WebParts/Views.

The CSR (my many incorrectly called JSLink) example that matches your question is:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-ccdb2a0e

---

CSR = The JavaScript that rewrites SharePoint data

JSLink = is the property of a WebPart that loads your CSR file

Remember:

The [(Chrome) Browser Extension Cisar editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar) is a WYSYWIG editor that gives you all the JavaScript boilerplate code and takes care of adding the JS files (with JSLink) to WebParts/Views.